# JQuery Find & Replace Characters in textarea from input text

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, find

What am I doing wrong here?

My HTML

```
<form name="frm">
   <textarea rows="10" id="uinput">some text here</textarea>
   find 1: <input type="text" id="findbox1" value="e">
   replace 1: <input type="text" id="replacebox1" value="666">
   find 2: <input type="text" id="findbox2" value="o">
   replace 2: <input type="text" id="replacebox2" value="000">
   find 3: <input type="text" id="findbox3" value="t">
   replace 3: <input type="text" id="replacebox3" value="777">
   <button type="button" id="fnrbtn">find and replace</button>
</form>
```

---

My JQuery

```
RegExp.escape = function(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
};

$("#fnrbtn").click(function() {
  var InputBox = $("#uInput").val(),
    FindWhat = $('#findbox' + i).val(),
    ReplaceWhat = $('#replacebox' + i).val(),
    NewInputBox = '',
    msg = '';
  for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
    msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + ": " + $('#findbox' + i).val() + " Replace #" + i + ": " + $('#replacebox' + i).val();
    NewInputBox = InputBox.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(FindWhat), "gi"), ReplaceWhat);
  }
  alert(msg);
  $("#uInput").val(NewInputBox);
  $('#uInput').select();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `FindWhat` and `ReplaceWhat` are placed outside of the `for` loop, while I think they must be inside.

Also, `counter` is not defined. You need to initialize it before use.

And your HTML contains `$("#uinput")`, not `$("#uInput")` as in the JQuery code.

Besides, you run replacements using the old value `InputBox`, not the modified value during the previous search and replace operation.

Here is a fixed code:

```js
RegExp.escape = function(str) {return String(str).replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');};

$("#fnrbtn").click(function () {
var InputBox = $("#uinput").val(); // uInput > uinput
msg = '';
counter = 4;
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
  FindWhat = $('#findbox' + i).val();
  ReplaceWhat = $('#replacebox' + i).val();

  msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + ": " + $('#findbox' + i).val() + " Replace #" + i + ": " + $('#replacebox' + i).val();
  InputBox = InputBox.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(FindWhat), "gi"), ReplaceWhat);
}
alert(msg);
$("#uinput").val(InputBox);
$('#uinput').select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frm">

<textarea rows="10" id="uinput">some text here</textarea>

find 1: <input type="text" id="findbox1" value="e">

replace 1: <input type="text" id="replacebox1" value="666">

find 2: <input type="text" id="findbox2" value="o">

replace 2: <input type="text" id="replacebox2" value="000">

find 3: <input type="text" id="findbox3" value="t">

replace 3: <input type="text" id="replacebox3" value="777">

<button type="button" id="fnrbtn">find and replace</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Does that help? Just curious because I have just noticed your deleted answer.